# JQuery how to add only the clicked image css class with nth-child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add `class="active"` to the clicked thumbnail image?

**HTML :**

```
<ul class="product-thumbnail">
    <li>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="Nile_1_16_0095.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="Nile_1_16_0096.jpg">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="Nile_1_16_0097.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS :**

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function () {
    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    $('ul > li:nth-child(' + index + ')').attr('class', 'active');
});
```

This will change all img classes to active. Instead I want only the clicked `img` to get the class `active`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: thanks to @gurvinder i could manage it to add class active to the clicked image. How can i manage to remove "active" class of the former image when i click the next image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.attr('class', 'active');` you should use `.addClass('active');` and you don't need index you could add class directly to the parent :

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function () {
    //remove class 'active' from all the lis
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active'); 

    //Add class 'active' to the clicked one
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome, now you can active multiple `li`s, is that what you want or you want to `active` just the last clicked?

Comment: the last clicked li. sorry for that not making it clear.

Comment: Check my updated answer using `siblings()` and `.removeClass()` methods to remove `àctive` class from other `li`s.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code you want to add the class at the `li` level rather than at the `img` level.

try

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function () {
   $(this).parent().addClass( 'active'); //go to the parent of the current element and add class active
});
```

> Instead i want only the clicked img to get the class "active"

if you want to add class at img level, then try this code

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function () {
   $(this).addClass( 'active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to understand:

```
var selector = $('.product-thumbnail img.thumbnail');
// select img tag with thumbnail class who are descendants of class product-thumbnail

selector.click(function(){
    selector.removeClass('active'); // remove class from all selector
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add class to clicked
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this is not working for you. This is how it should be done. i.e,

```
    $(".thumbnail").click(function () {
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
    $('ul > li:nth-child(' + index + ')').attr('class', 'active');
    });
```

will work fine.The only issue is that the index that you get in the index var needs to be incremented by 1 to select the right element.

Change:
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
to:
        var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;